# how to calculate distance while driving in android map?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am creating an app for taxi with google map. I Have 2 buttons start and stop. when driver click on start button i need to record his distance from start point while driver is driving taxi on map and when he click on end button show the complete recorded distance that he travelled. 
Please help me.

Comment: Check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/)

Comment: Please note that this site is not a code writing service. If
you [edit] your question to describe what you have tried so
far and where you are stuck, then we can try to help with
specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: hello brother its my project, ashish is my friend. In our project i need to record distance when driver start driver. can you help me @Toby Speight

Comment: can you see again @Toby Speight

Comment: There's still no code in the question